# What defines an XSS vulnerability? (my case)

Tags: xss

I was in a bug bounty. I can't be sure of this problem because it's all over the website.

Will this be harmful for the organization?

When I exit the angular brackets and paste the payload, it pops up an alert:

[image: Here is the screenshot]

Comment: What do you mean by "paste the payload"? What you describe has nothing to do with XSS. For XSS, first you enter text in one of application input fields (if it is GUI) or provide malicious data to the server in some other way (e.g. call public API). Server application stores the data. Later on these data are loaded to the client and rendered. Please describe all the steps that you have done.

Comment: i said if i quit the brackets and put the payload will it be considered as xss. my concern was; this wasn't in the input field like not a search box or anything else. so this is not an xss vuln i guess. thanks for reply.

Comment: As I said, you should first *enter* your payload somewhere. You don't enter it anywhere. I don't see anything related to XSS.

Comment: This isn't an XSS issue or a security issue. You appear to have manipulated your local copy of the code.

Answer (score 2):

If you use the browser developer tools to edit the page code, that's not a vulnerability in the web page, as you are using a back door.

Comment: thanks. been away from xss and got excited for a sec.

Answer (score 1):

When you're not sure if there's a vulnerability or not, it might be helpful to come up with concrete attack scenarios: What exactly would you as an attacker do to exploit the alleged vulnerability *against a victim*, and what would you achieve by that?

Of course you can modify the HTML structure in your *own* browser and run all kinds of JavaScript code, but the point of an XSS attack is that you're able to execute code in *somebody else's* browser. There are different attack scenarios for that:

- You've managed to make the web application save and load the code in an unsafe manner, so that it will be executed in the victim's browser when the victim visits some page (Stored XSS).
- You've crafted e. g. a URL or HTML form, so that when a victim visits the URL or submits the form, some code is executed in the victim's browser (Reflected XSS or DOM-based XSS).

So far, you haven't shown any of this.

Comment: As @Ángel mentioned, it seems that the author just manipulated the DOM via Developer Tools. Thus it has nothing to do with XSS.

Comment: I know. I was trying to explain to the OP how they can find out for themselves that there is no vulnerability -- by realizing that there isn't any plausible attack scenario.